# How to get rid of unnecessary words and symbols form df?

Tags: json, pandas, list, dictionary, datatables

**I need get rid of unnecessary words and symbols and just leave genres.**

| id | genres |
| --- | --- |
| 19995 | [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}] |
| 285 | [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}] |

tried this

```
json.loads(movies['genre'][0]).values()
```

but error

```
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

[[image]]

**I need this**

| id | genres |
| --- | --- |
| 19995 | Action,Adventure,Fantasy,Science,Fiction |
| 285 | Adventure,Fantasy,Action |
|  |  |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` with generator comprehension for extract `name`s to joined strings:

```
movies['genres'] = movies['genres'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(y['name'] for y in x))
```

Or:

```
movies['genres'] = [','.join(y['name'] for y in x) for x in movies['genres']]
```

If possible some `name` keys not exist use:

```
movies['genres'] = movies['genres'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(y['name'] for y in x if 'name' in y))
```